# ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend"

Tags: npm, babeljs

I am trying to run exercises on exercism but I am getting this error `ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend"` whenever I am trying to run the test with `npm install` below is my package.json file and the error log. What do I need to do?

Thank you.
[I was able to put the link on github gist](https://gist.github.com/uzorjchibuzor/948cdeff5b03442234b5f8ab85c6465b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran this command `npm i babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend` on the terminal and it solved my problem. Thanks all